# listview.builder disposing card widget every time the page refreshes

Tags: flutter

I am trying to display a card list of activities from an array, and the list only displays the first time the application loads. [This is what it initially looks like when the app first loads](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQ4nu.jpg)

When I navigate to any other page and back to the home page, the card list does not display.
[This is the page after navigating to a different page and back](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Rum7.jpg)

Below is the code to display the activities list:

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:mesys/models/activity_model.dart';
import 'package:mesys/network_utils/api.dart';

class ActivityCard extends StatefulWidget {
  const ActivityCard({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ActivityCardState createState() => _ActivityCardState();
}

class _ActivityCardState extends State<ActivityCard> {
  final List<ActivityModel> _activities = <ActivityModel>[];

  Future<List<ActivityModel>> _fetchActivities() async {
    var res = await Network().getData('users/activities');

    var activities = <ActivityModel>[];

    if (res.statusCode == 200) {
      var body = json.decode(res.body);
      var tdata = body['data'];
      var activitiesJson = tdata;
      for (var activityJson in activitiesJson) {
        activities.add(ActivityModel.fromJson(activityJson));
      }
    }
    return activities;
  }



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _fetchActivities().then((value) {
      _activities.addAll(value);
    });
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: _activities.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return Card(
            child: Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                    top: 32.0, bottom: 32.0, left: 16.0, right: 16.0),
                child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      RichText(
                          text: TextSpan(children: [
                        const TextSpan(
                            text: 'Activity Name: ',
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 14,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                color: Colors.black)),
                        TextSpan(
                            text: _activities[index].title,
                            style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black))
                      ])),
                      RichText(
                          text: const TextSpan(children: [
                        TextSpan(
                            text: 'Activity Description: ',
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 14,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                color: Colors.black)),
                  
                      ]))
                    ])));
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Please let me know why it isn't displaying

Answer (score 1):

I can't see where you are calling `_fetchActivities()` but for your case it should work by using `initState()`. With this you can make sure calling functions on initial page load once. `initState()` doesn't support `async`, so call it like this:

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    asyncMethod();
  }

  void asyncMethod() async {
    await _fetchActivities()
    // ....
  }
```

More on `initState()` [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/initState.html)

Comment: To add to this, the `build` method should have no side effects like calling an API asynchronously. [From the docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatelessWidget/build.html): _This method can potentially be called in every frame and should not have any side effects beyond building a widget._

Comment: yes thats right. The initstate method is called before the build method so you are able to fetch data and react in the UI with the given data. That seems to make more sense for me here. We can also prevent calling the _fetchActivities() multiple times with initstate() since in the build method _fetchActivities() would unnecessarily rebuild everytime a setstate is getting called